# Why does Flutter try to render '/' rather than my `initialRoute`?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a Flutter app in which I'm trying to dive deeper into routing.  When I use the `home` property within my `MaterialApp` widget, it seems to be perfectly happy.  As soon as I change it to use `initialRoute`, the app crashes with a `NoSuchMethodError` and an error that says `The builder for route '/' returned null` - my initial route is `'/loading'`.

#### Errors:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'new MyApp.<anonymous closure>'
Receiver: Closure: (BuildContext) => LoadingScreen
Tried calling: new MyApp.<anonymous closure>(Instance of 'StatelessElement', null)
Found: new MyApp.<anonymous closure>(BuildContext) => LoadingScreen

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///Users/tanner/Documents/Coding/Courses/AppBrewery/Flutter/Clima-Flutter/lib/main.dart:18:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      MyApp._buildRoute (package:clima/main.dart:54:30)
#2      MyApp._makeRoute (package:clima/main.dart:43:26)
#3      MyApp._generateRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:clima/main.dart:27:42)
#4      MaterialPageRoute.buildPage (package:flutter/src/material/page.dart:87:27)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The builder for route "/" returned null.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///Users/tanner/Documents/Coding/Courses/AppBrewery/Flutter/Clima-Flutter/lib/main.dart:18:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

#### My Routing Weirdness

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, Function> _routes = {
    '/loading': (BuildContext context, LoadingScreenArguments args) =>
        LoadingScreen(args),
    '/location': (BuildContext context, LocationScreenArguments args) =>
        LocationScreen(args),
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
//      home: LoadingScreen(),
      initialRoute: '/loading',
      onGenerateRoute: _generateRoute,
    );
  }

  MaterialPageRoute _generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => _makeRoute(
        context: context,
        routeName: settings.name,
        arguments: settings.arguments,
      ),
      maintainState: true,
      fullscreenDialog: false,
    );
  }

  Widget _makeRoute({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required String routeName,
    Object arguments,
  }) {
    final Widget child = _buildRoute(
        context: context, routeName: routeName, arguments: arguments);
    return child;
  }

  Widget _buildRoute({
    @required BuildContext context,
    @required String routeName,
    Object arguments,
  }) {
    print(routeName);
    return _routes[routeName](context, arguments);
  }
}
```

Comment: change `/loading` to `loading` - now it tries to create two routes: `/` and `/loading`

Comment: @pskink - That worked!!  Why would it try to create both `/` and `/loading`?  Does the Navigator try to match using pattern matching similar to a web app and so it will attempt to match any `/` before `/**`?

Comment: That's a huge help!  If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct one!

Comment: feel free to write a self answer ;-)

Comment: btw you could also use `MaterilApp.onGenerateInitialRoutes` but its a rather new feature...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment on my answer by @pskink, the solution is pretty apparent:  Removing the leading `/` solves the problem.

This [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L1634) in the source code reveals that the `Navigator` will split the string on `/` characters and loads the route for each chunk in order to preserve a traceable history.

Answer (score 0):

It's because it can't find any route named '/loading', because you have made a `route` map of `<String, Function>` whereas routes are `WidgetBuilder`'s.

So try replacing:

```
Map<String, Function>
```

with:

```
Map<String, WidgetBuilder>
```

Comment: This throws lint errors because it doesn't want me to pass the arguments object down to the widget.  Any thoughts?